# 1D Finite Difference Time Domain (FDTD) in CUDA for the Helmholtz equation

Tags: cuda

My 1D wave equation is slower when I implement it in CUDA than it is in C/C++. Could any one tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
__global__ void Solver1d(float* up, float* u, float* um)
{
    int id;
    float dx,dt;
    dx = (float)L/n;
    dt = (float)dx/c;
    float r= c*((float)dt/dx);
    float R = r*r;

    // index mapping between data and threads
    id = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;

    // Allowing all threads in the range of valids data to execute
    if (id<n)
    {
        if(id==0)
        {
            up[id]=0;
        }
        else if(id==n-1)
        {
            up[n-1]=0;
        }
        else
        {
            up[id] = 2*u[id]-um[id]+R*(u[id+1]-2*u[id]+u[id-1]);    
        }   
    }
}

// main program
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{        

    // declare all variables 
    int i;
    float inner,L2_exact,ue[n],dx,dt;
    dx = (float)L/n;
    dt = (float)(0.05*dx/c); // Max time step
    float r= c*((float)dt/dx);
    float R = r*r;

    // Allocate memory on host
    //float u=(float *)malloc((n)*sizeof(float));
    //float um=(float *)malloc((n)*sizeof(float));
    float up[n],um[n],u[n];


    //Pointers for device memory allocation
    float *dev_up, *dev_u, *dev_um;


    // Allocating memory to device (GPU)
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_up, n*sizeof(float)));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_u, n*sizeof(float)));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_um, n*sizeof(float)));


    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    float elapsedTime;

    // Start timer
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventCreate( &start ));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventCreate( &stop ));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventRecord( start,0 ));

    //Initialize the stream
    cudaStream_t stream;
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaStreamCreate( &stream ));
    //Initial condition
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        u[i]=sin(2*PI*i*dx);
        //printf("Initialization ok\n");
    }

    // Enforcing special formula for t = -1
    for(i=1;i<n-1 ;i++)
    {
        um[0] = 0;
        um[n-1] = 0;
        um[i] = u[i]  + 0.5*R*(u[i-1] - 2*u[i] + u[i+1]); //+ 0.5*dt*dt*f(i*dx,t)
        //printf("um is runing fine\n");
    }

    // setting blocks and threads numbers
    int noThreads=128;
    dim3 dimBlock(noThreads,1,1);
    dim3 dimGrid(1+n/(noThreads-1),1,1);

    // move u and um to GPU
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(dev_u, u, n*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(dev_um, um, n*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    float t=0;

    //int counter=0;
    while(t<=T)
    {
        //counter++;
        t += dt;

        Solver1d<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(dev_up,dev_u,dev_um);
        // cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            um[i] = u[i];
            u[i]  = up[i];
        }

    }

    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventRecord( stop,0 ));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventSynchronize( stop ));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventElapsedTime( &elapsedTime,start,stop ));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventDestroy( start ));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaEventDestroy( stop ));     

    printf("elapsed time: %lf sec\n",elapsedTime/1000);
    // move the solution up from GPU to CPU
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(up, dev_up, n*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(u, dev_u, n*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(um, dev_um, n*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    int j;
    float L2cpuSolution=0.0;
    float L2gpuSolution=0.0;
    float ERROR_PERCENTAGE=0.0;


    // Verification with exact solution
    for(j=0;j<(n);j++)
    {
        //printf("up[%d]=%.12g\n",j,up[j]);
        ue[j]=0.5*(sin(2*PI*(j*dx+c*T))+sin(2*PI*(j*dx-c*T)));
        //printf("um[%d]=%.12g\n",j,um[j]);
        inner += (ue[j]-up[j])*(ue[j]-up[j]);
        L2cpuSolution += ue[j]*ue[j];
        L2gpuSolution += up[j]*up[j];

    }
    L2cpuSolution = sqrt(L2cpuSolution)/n;
    L2gpuSolution = sqrt(L2gpuSolution)/n;
    L2_exact = sqrt(inner/(n));
    ERROR_PERCENTAGE = 100*(L2_exact/L2cpuSolution);
    printf("L2_exact=%lf\n",L2_exact);
    printf("gpul2=%lf, and cpuL2=%lf \n",L2gpuSolution,L2cpuSolution);
    printf("ERROR_PERCENTAGE= %lf\n", ERROR_PERCENTAGE);

    // Free device memory
    cudaFree(dev_up);
    cudaFree(dev_u);
    cudaFree(dev_um);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Where is `n` defined? Which is its value? How did you time the CPU version? Note that you are also taking into account the `Initial condition` and the `Enforcing special formula` within the GPU time.

Comment: Also there is a loop inside the while loop that updates host array um and u and later you are replacing the content with a cudaMemcpy call. Remove this loop and measure again.

Comment: What is the value of T,L,n,c? You are also creating a stream but never using it and never destroying it. Remove the stream creation.

Comment: Perhaps a good question to ask is why you think something as trivial as a first order, 1D finite difference method should be faster on a GPU than a host CPU?

Comment: what's the value of n?

Comment: @talonmies Because it can be faster. The data just needs to be large enough.

Comment: @user2114645 There can be couple of issues. 1) Your data sizes are small. 2) You are using an older generation card which may not have cache support. In case of (2) you may want to use shared memory instead of reading from global memory multiple times.

Comment: @talonmies I fully agree with Pavan. Even the addition of two vectors is "trivial", but you would like to execute it on the GPU. Understanding the reasons why this code for the solution of the 1d time-domain wave equation is slower or not than the CPU counterpart is very important for the community. For example, in 1d time-domain inverse scattering, the iterative solution of the 1d time-domain wave equation is performed at each iteration step, so it is worth to be accelerated, see the paper Inverse Scattering and Imaging using Broadband Time-Domain Data by Chew, Weedon and Moghaddam.

Comment: @user2114645 Please, provide the values of the global constants T,L,n,c, as also suggested by brano and Soroosh and possibly the CPU code, so I could make a check on my GPUs. Also, I would recommend to change to title of the post. The current does not tell too much of anything. Thanks.

Comment: Also of note: GPUs HATE branching. Get rid if your boundary checks, and adjust the domain. Also make sure you're only timing kernel execution time - not host:device:host copy time, CUDA initialization, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, I don't think you're doing anything wrong here. However, you shouldn't expect CUDA to do magic for you and be loads faster than a CPU implementation. Especially something relatively trivial as a 1-D wave equation (which is really just a single for-loop in a CPU implementation) is so simple for a modern computer that there is little reason to parallelise it. Because remember: the data transfer from host to device and back again can be a bottleneck in the performance of a GPU implementation. So unless your data size is massive (say n > 10^6 or so), I don't think it'd be worth it.

However, one way of improving the code in your kernel would be to precompute a number of your variables. The variables `dx`, `dt`, `r`, and `R` seem to be constant throughout your entire simulation, but you have each little thread compute them at each time step. So that's probably millions and millions of superfluous computation. Also, using texture memory for the data of your array has a potential of improving the speed, as most of your memory access takes place in the same neighbourhood for each block.

Comment: Your answer contains a LOT of assumptions: that the solution domain is relatively small, that the application isn't performing a LOT of iterations (say, like an FDTD simulation, which this appears to be), etc. Even 1D sims can take an inordinate amount of processing power if the problem size, or run length, is big.

Comment: This is true, but these assumptions are the main reasons why a Finite Difference simulation may not perform as well on the GPU as on the CPU, next to the other suggestions mentioned above, and simply the type of GPU.

Comment: I see your point. FDTD (specifically - I have approximately zero experience with Finite Element or modified FDTD algorithms, so my views may not apply), however, is "embarrassingly parallel." My first OpenCL attempt ran about 50x faster on a GTX580 than on an i7 2.6Ghz. There's certainly overhead with a GPU-based simulation, but if you're running for enough frames to compensate for setup time, and don't have to move data back and forth between the host and compute device too frequently, it works out in your favor to use the GPU. (BTW, +1 - great answer, I just felt it was incomplete.)

Comment: Very true, I'm definitely not discarding a GPU approach here! I've been doing a lot of FDTD stuff myself, and my experience is that for 2D and 3D cases, CUDA implementations definitely provide great speed-up. But for 1D cases (like this one here) the domain generally isn't large enough to make it worth it, unless you're modelling a 1D string of a million nodes or so, but then there are many better and faster techniques to obtain similar results (such as digital waveguides or frequency domain modelling).

Comment: Yeah, I'm having trouble coming up with a scenario where it would be worthwhile to move 1D to the GPU. But, I've learned not to discount the possibility of weird approaches that initially seem silly. ( or the possibility that apparently useful approaches are ACTUALLY silly.) im also doing 2D and 3D FDTD work. Id love to hear what you're working on. DavidLively @ gmail if you feel like comparing notes

Answer (score 2):

The main question and discussion in the comments above is whether 1D Finite Difference Time Domain (FDTD) method can be faster when implemented C/C++ and run on a sequential machine rather than when implemented in CUDA and run on a parallel GPU.

I'm trying to answer this question with the below code. It contains both an implementation of the 1D FDTD method for an electromagnetic application in C/C++ and CUDA. Theory and C/C++ implementations are taken from [Understanding the Finite-Difference Time-Domain Method](http://www.eecs.wsu.edu/~schneidj/ufdtd/ufdtd.pdf) (see Program 3.1). The CUDA version contains two approaches, one using global memory only and one using shared memory. In the latter case, I enforce synchronization between magnetic field and electric field updates by launching two different kernels.

For a sufficiently large problem (`SIZE = 10000000`), the GPU version is indeed faster than the CPU one. I have tested the code on a Kepler K20c card and these are the results:

```
Shared Memory version
CPU elapsed time = 3980.763 ms
GPU elapsed time = 356.828 ms

Global Memory version
GPU elapsed time = 359.768 ms
```

The version using shared memory does not improve the scenario.

Here is the code:

**kernel.cu**

```
/* 1D FDTD simulation with an additive source. */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "TimingCPU.h"
#include "TimingGPU.cuh"

#define BLOCKSIZE   512
//#define DEBUG

/*******************/
/* iDivUp FUNCTION */
/*******************/
int iDivUp(int a, int b) { return ((a % b) != 0) ? (a / b + 1) : (a / b); }

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

/***********************************/
/* HOST-SIZE FIELD UPDATE FUNCTION */
/***********************************/
void updateHost(double *h_ez, double* h_hy, double imp0, double qTime, const int source, const int N) {

    /* update magnetic field */
    for (int mm = 0; mm < N - 1; mm++)
        h_hy[mm] = h_hy[mm] + (h_ez[mm + 1] - h_ez[mm]) / imp0;

    /* update electric field */
    for (int mm = 1; mm < N; mm++)
        h_ez[mm] = h_ez[mm] + (h_hy[mm] - h_hy[mm - 1]) * imp0;

    /* use additive source at node 50 */
    h_ez[source] += exp(-(qTime - 30.) * (qTime - 30.) / 100.);

}

/********************************************************/
/* DEVICE-SIZE FIELD UPDATE FUNCTION - NO SHARED MEMORY */
/********************************************************/
__global__ void updateDevice_v0(double *d_ez, double* d_hy, double imp0, double qTime, const int source, const int N) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    /* update magnetic field */
    if (tid < N-1) d_hy[tid] = d_hy[tid] + (d_ez[tid + 1] - d_ez[tid]) / imp0;

    __threadfence();

    /* update electric field */
    if ((tid < N)&&(tid > 0)) d_ez[tid] = d_ez[tid] + (d_hy[tid] - d_hy[tid - 1]) * imp0;

    /* use additive source at node 50 */
    if (tid == source) d_ez[tid] += exp(-(qTime - 30.) * (qTime - 30.) / 100.);

}

/**************************************************************/
/* DEVICE-SIZE MAGNETIC FIELD UPDATE FUNCTION - SHARED MEMORY */
/**************************************************************/
__global__ void updateDevice_hy(double *d_ez, double* d_hy, double imp0, double qTime, const int source, const int N) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    __shared__ double hy_temp[BLOCKSIZE+1], ez_temp[BLOCKSIZE+1];

    hy_temp[threadIdx.x] = d_hy[tid];
    ez_temp[threadIdx.x] = d_ez[tid];

    if ((threadIdx.x == 0)&&((tid + BLOCKSIZE) < N)) {
        ez_temp[BLOCKSIZE] = d_ez[tid + BLOCKSIZE];
        hy_temp[BLOCKSIZE] = d_hy[tid + BLOCKSIZE];
    }

    __syncthreads();

    /* update magnetic field */
    if (tid < N-1) d_hy[tid] = hy_temp[threadIdx.x] + (ez_temp[threadIdx.x + 1] - ez_temp[threadIdx.x]) / imp0;

}

/**************************************************************/
/* DEVICE-SIZE ELECTRIC FIELD UPDATE FUNCTION - SHARED MEMORY */
/**************************************************************/
__global__ void updateDevice_ez(double *d_ez, double* d_hy, double imp0, double qTime, const int source, const int N) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    __shared__ double hy_temp[BLOCKSIZE+1], ez_temp[BLOCKSIZE+1];

    hy_temp[threadIdx.x + 1] = d_hy[tid];
    ez_temp[threadIdx.x + 1] = d_ez[tid];

    if ((threadIdx.x == 0)&&(tid >= 1)) {
        ez_temp[0] = d_ez[tid - 1];
        hy_temp[0] = d_hy[tid - 1];
    }

    __syncthreads();

    /* update electric field */
    ez_temp[threadIdx.x] = ez_temp[threadIdx.x + 1] + (hy_temp[threadIdx.x + 1] - hy_temp[threadIdx.x]) * imp0;

    /* use additive source at node 50 */
    if (tid == source) ez_temp[threadIdx.x] += exp(-(qTime - 30.) * (qTime - 30.) / 100.);

    if ((tid < N)&&(tid > 0)) d_ez[tid] = ez_temp[threadIdx.x];

}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    // --- Problem size
    const int SIZE = 10000000;

    // --- Free-space wave impedance
    double imp0 = 377.0;

    // --- Maximum number of iterations (must be less than the problem size)
    int maxTime = 100;

    // --- Source location
    int source = SIZE / 2;

    // --- Host side memory allocations and initializations
    double *h_ez = (double*)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(double));
    double *h_hy = (double*)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(double));

    // --- Device side memory allocations and initializations
    double *d_ez; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_ez, SIZE * sizeof(double)));
    double *d_hy; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_hy, SIZE * sizeof(double)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemset(d_ez, 0, SIZE * sizeof(double)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemset(d_hy, 0, SIZE * sizeof(double)));

    // --- Host side memory allocations for debugging purposes
#ifdef DEBUG
    double *h_ez_temp = (double*)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(double));
    double *h_hy_temp = (double*)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(double));
#endif

    // --- Host-side time-steppings
#ifndef DEBUG
    TimingCPU timerCPU;
    timerCPU.StartCounter();
    for (int qTime = 0; qTime < maxTime; qTime++) {
        updateHost(h_ez, h_hy, imp0, qTime, source, SIZE);
    }
    printf("CPU elapsed time = %3.3f ms\n", timerCPU.GetCounter());
#endif

    TimingGPU timerGPU;
    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    // --- Device-side time-steppings
    for (int qTime = 0; qTime < maxTime; qTime++) {

        updateDevice_v0<<<iDivUp(SIZE, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>(d_ez, d_hy, imp0, qTime, source, SIZE);
//      updateDevice_hy<<<iDivUp(SIZE, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>(d_ez, d_hy, imp0, qTime, source, SIZE);
//      updateDevice_ez<<<iDivUp(SIZE, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>(d_ez, d_hy, imp0, qTime, source, SIZE);
#ifdef DEBUG
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_ez_temp, d_ez, SIZE * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_hy_temp, d_hy, SIZE * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

        updateHost(h_ez, h_hy, imp0, qTime, source, SIZE);
        for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
            printf("%f %f %f %f\n",h_ez_temp[i], h_ez[i], h_hy_temp[i], h_hy[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
#endif
    }
    printf("GPU elapsed time = %3.3f ms\n", timerGPU.GetCounter());

    return 0;
}
```

**TimingCPU.h**

```
#ifndef __TIMINGCPU_H__
#define __TIMINGCPU_H__

#ifdef __linux__

    class TimingCPU {

        private:
            long cur_time_;

        public:

            TimingCPU();

            ~TimingCPU();

            void StartCounter();

            double GetCounter();
    };

#elif _WIN32 || _WIN64

    struct PrivateTimingCPU;

    class TimingCPU
    {
        private:
            PrivateTimingCPU *privateTimingCPU;

        public:

            TimingCPU();

            ~TimingCPU();

            void StartCounter();

            double GetCounter();

    }; // TimingCPU class

#endif

#endif
```

**TimingCPU.cpp**

```
/**************/
/* TIMING CPU */
/**************/

#include "TimingCPU.h"

#ifdef __linux__

    #include <sys/time.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    TimingCPU::TimingCPU(): cur_time_(0) { StartCounter(); }

    TimingCPU::~TimingCPU() { }

    void TimingCPU::StartCounter()
    {
        struct timeval time;
        if(gettimeofday( &time, 0 )) return;
        cur_time_ = 1000000 * time.tv_sec + time.tv_usec;
    }

    double TimingCPU::GetCounter()
    {
        struct timeval time;
        if(gettimeofday( &time, 0 )) return -1;

        long cur_time = 1000000 * time.tv_sec + time.tv_usec;
        double sec = (cur_time - cur_time_) / 1000000.0;
        if(sec < 0) sec += 86400;
        cur_time_ = cur_time;

        return 1000.*sec;
    }

#elif _WIN32 || _WIN64
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <iostream>

    struct PrivateTimingCPU {
        double  PCFreq;
        __int64 CounterStart;
    };

    // --- Default constructor
    TimingCPU::TimingCPU() { privateTimingCPU = new PrivateTimingCPU; (*privateTimingCPU).PCFreq = 0.0; (*privateTimingCPU).CounterStart = 0; }

    // --- Default destructor
    TimingCPU::~TimingCPU() { }

    // --- Starts the timing
    void TimingCPU::StartCounter()
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER li;
        if(!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li)) std::cout << "QueryPerformanceFrequency failed!\n";

        (*privateTimingCPU).PCFreq = double(li.QuadPart)/1000.0;

        QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
        (*privateTimingCPU).CounterStart = li.QuadPart;
    }

    // --- Gets the timing counter in ms
    double TimingCPU::GetCounter()
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER li;
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
        return double(li.QuadPart-(*privateTimingCPU).CounterStart)/(*privateTimingCPU).PCFreq;
    }
#endif
```

**TimingGPU.cuh**

```
#ifndef __TIMING_CUH__
#define __TIMING_CUH__

/**************/
/* TIMING GPU */
/**************/

// Events are a part of CUDA API and provide a system independent way to measure execution times on CUDA devices with approximately 0.5
// microsecond precision.

struct PrivateTimingGPU;

class TimingGPU
{
    private:
        PrivateTimingGPU *privateTimingGPU;

    public:

        TimingGPU();

        ~TimingGPU();

        void StartCounter();
        void StartCounterFlags();

        float GetCounter();

}; // TimingCPU class

#endif
```

**TimingGPU.cu**

```
/**************/
/* TIMING GPU */
/**************/

#include "TimingGPU.cuh"

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

struct PrivateTimingGPU {
    cudaEvent_t     start;
    cudaEvent_t     stop;
};

// default constructor
TimingGPU::TimingGPU() { privateTimingGPU = new PrivateTimingGPU; }

// default destructor
TimingGPU::~TimingGPU() { }

void TimingGPU::StartCounter()
{
    cudaEventCreate(&((*privateTimingGPU).start));
    cudaEventCreate(&((*privateTimingGPU).stop));
    cudaEventRecord((*privateTimingGPU).start,0);
}

void TimingGPU::StartCounterFlags()
{
    int eventflags = cudaEventBlockingSync;

    cudaEventCreateWithFlags(&((*privateTimingGPU).start),eventflags);
    cudaEventCreateWithFlags(&((*privateTimingGPU).stop),eventflags);
    cudaEventRecord((*privateTimingGPU).start,0);
}

// Gets the counter in ms
float TimingGPU::GetCounter()
{
    float   time;
    cudaEventRecord((*privateTimingGPU).stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize((*privateTimingGPU).stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time,(*privateTimingGPU).start,(*privateTimingGPU).stop);
    return time;
}
```